# Two cross-platform implementations of getline in C

Tags: c, comparative-review, file, portability

I created my cross-platform implementations of `getline` function in C.

It takes different arguments and have different return values than 'original' `getline` function, but aim is the same. The only argument `input_file` is file from which the line have to be read.  Return value is the line read from file or NULL if nothing read.

Here is one implementation, using `fgets()`:

```
static inline char*
getline(FILE* input_file){
    const unsigned int chunk_size=256;
    char* line=malloc(chunk_size*sizeof*line+1);
    if(line==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Fatal: failed to allocate %zu bytes.\n",chunk_size*sizeof*line+1);
        exit(1);
    }
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;;++i){
        memset(line+chunk_size*i,0,chunk_size);
        if(fgets(line+chunk_size*i,chunk_size+1,input_file)==NULL)
            break;
        if(line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n')
            break;
        char* tmp=realloc(line,chunk_size*(i+2)*sizeof*line+1);
        if(tmp==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"Fatal: failed to allocate %zu bytes.\n",chunk_size*(i+2)*sizeof*line+1);
            exit(1);
        }else
            line=tmp;
    }
    if(strlen(line)==0){
        free(line);
        return NULL;
    }else{
        line[strlen(line)-1]=0;
        return line;
    }
}
```

Here is my second implementation, using `fgetc()`:

```
static inline char*
getline(FILE* input_file){
    const unsigned int chunk_size=3;
    char* line=calloc(chunk_size,sizeof*line+1);
    if(line==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Fatal: failed to allocate %zu bytes.\n",chunk_size*sizeof*line+1);
        exit(1);
    }
    char c;
    unsigned int i,j;
    for(i=0,j=1;;++i){
        c=(char)fgetc(input_file);
        if(c==EOF||c=='\n')
            break;
        line[i]=c;
        if(i==chunk_size*j){
            ++j;
            char* tmp=realloc(line,chunk_size*(j+1)*sizeof*line+1);
            if(tmp==NULL){
                fprintf(stderr,"Fatal: failed to allocate %zu bytes.\n",chunk_size*(j+1)*sizeof*line+1);
                exit(1);
            }else{
                line=tmp;
                memset(line+chunk_size*j,0,chunk_size);
            }
        }
    }
    if(strlen(line)==0){
        free(line);
        return NULL;
    }else{
        line[strlen(line)]=0;
        return line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`exit(1)` is probably a bad idea, so is `fprintf` to `stderr`.  We don't know how big the string can be, therefore running out of memory could be valid, and if `stderr` is redirected to somewhere a client can see. `realloc` should already set `errno` to `ENOMEM`, so you could probably just return `NULL`, and modify comment that upon returning `NULL`, caller should check `errno`. Or maybe you should return empty string if there's no data, and use `NULL` to indicate error.

change `calloc` to `malloc`, as you anyway `NULL` terminate the string in your `fgetc` implementation.

Instead of having this code duplicated for error message (which I vote against), and actual calculation: `chunk_size*(j+1)*sizeof*line+1`, you could create a variable and use it in both places, therefore you know you print exactly what you did, and there wasn't a mistake if you had to change the calculation slightly.

Try this on windows (as it claims to be a cross platform implementation), but from memory `fgetc` will return `'\r'`, which you'll put right into the line, whereas I'm pretty sure `fgets` won't return `'\r'`, when the line terminator is `"\r\n"`; I believe `fgets` returns `"\n"`, not `"\r\n"` on windows, even if `"\r\n"` is in the input stream.

You don't need to assign data to `tmp` like this: `char* tmp=realloc(line,chunk_size*(i+2)*sizeof*line+1);` as upon success you always do: `line=tmp`, and upon failure, line will no longer point to valid memory. So you could just assign to `line`.

Notice how you're calling `malloc/calloc/realloc`, I would add a `freeline` function to your code in order to free any memory allocated by this code.  The caller may not be using the same `malloc/calloc/realloc` you're using, and their `free` may not be compatible.

Finally I'm not really sure about this: `chunk_size*(j+1)*sizeof*line+1`
I think you want: `chunk_size*(j+1)*sizeof*char+1`, as I think `line` is of size `4` or maybe even `8`?, print it out in the debugger, and see, I think you're allocating a lot more memory then you end up putting into the array.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your answer has a lot of claims in it ("I'm pretty sure ...", "I think ...") and it would be nice to back these up with some references to documentation resources.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that although many `realloc()` implementations set `errno` as you claim (and POSIX mandates it), that's not in the C Standard, so a conforming implementation may exist which doesn't do that.

Comment: Ok, if the errno is not set for some reason, I would recommend setting it explicitly from the method. This might be a good idea in either case, as it makes the intention explicit, vs. relying on underlying code; Also if there is still going to be an fprintf to report on error, it may change the errno to something else, thus setting it right before returning would be good.